# Ruby: Dir.chdir using data from a text file in windows

Tags: ruby, windows, directory, chdir

I am trying to use a script to change the working directory using Dir.chdir

This works:

```
dirs = ['//servername/share','//servername2/share']

dirs.each do |dir|
  Dir.chdir dir
end
```

If I put the above share information into a text file (each share on a new line) and try to load:

```
File.foreach("shares.txt") {|dir|
  Dir.chdir dir
}
```

I get this error:

> 'chdir': No such file or directory - //servername/share (Errno::ENOENT)

How can I read the shares from a text file and change to that directory? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
Dir.chdir dir.strip
```

or

```
Dir.chdir dir.chomp
```

Reason:
With `File.foreach` you get lines including a newlines (`\n`).

`strip` will delete leading and trailing spaces, `chomp` will delete trailing newlines.

---

Another possibility: In your example you use absolute paths. This should work.

If you use relative paths, then check, in which directory you are (you change it!). To keep the directory you may use the block-version of `Dir.chdir`.